# Node - P2P Webrtc-Star

Tags: node.js, p2p

I am following a tutorial on how to create a colabrative document. The github is below. It uses ipfs for the P2P aspect.

https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/shared-editing-demo

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: no protocol with name: libp2p-webrtc-star
```

I have searched and found possible solutions e.g. changing the config found in the link below but it has not worked:

https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/issues/1029

```
config: { // overload the default config
    Addresses: {
        Swarm: [
            "/dns4/star-signal.cloud.ipfs.team/wss/p2p-webrtc-star"
        ],
        API: '',
        Gateway: ''
    },
  }
})
```

The above does not work as I still get the same error. There was a mention (on the github) of swarm having both the old and the new config together and that is why the error is being thrown. However, I am unsure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

i had that with `0.41.0` version. also try to use `/dns4/ws-star.discovery.libp2p.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p-websocket-star`

switch back to `0.40.0` worked for me